# Unable to connect to remote SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

So, I'm having trouble connecting to my remote SQL Express server running on my Server 2008R2 application test server with IIS7, .NET Framework 4.5 and WebDeploy. I have setup my sql server with the guidance provided from Microsoft. As you can see I have done the following :

**Disabled the firewall (for testing) :**
[image]
**Checked that services are running :**
[image]
**Made sure TCP / IP is enabled :**
[image]

I have no troubles connecting internally on the local computer, with the Managment Studio.
(User "Christian" is added with management studio, as a local user).  When I click add a new SQL connection wizard in Visual Studio 2013 I get the following error :

[image]

As you can see from the images, the connection Wizard automatically find the correct server on the network. I have tested with the following "Server Names"

- 192.168.1.111
- 192.168.1.111\SQLEXPRESS
- 192.168.1.111.\SQLEXPRESS
- WIN-NVAAFR9N703
- WIN-NVAAFR9N703\SQLEXPRESS
- WIN-NVAAFR9N703.\SQLEXPRESS

I know there are several other threads about this issue, most resolved by activating "TCP/IP" in the Configuration manager. But this does not seem to do the trick for me. The network and routers should not be the issue here. As all other network applications seems to work just fine. I do use a separat system, (DVB Viewer). This program does have a web-frontend on port :8089, but I am unsure if it runs it own SQL server. I read something about XAMPP, but I'm unable to find any httpd.conf on the system.

Comment: What is your configuration for _Protocols_ under the _SQL Server Network Configuration_ entry (right below _SQL Native Client 10.0 Configuration_). Is TCP/IP activated there?

Comment: +1 for detailed Question which made it easy to be answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot shows the client protocols, you need to make sure the protocols are enabled for your SQLEXPRESS server instance:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You sir, are my hero. A stupid mistake. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

The default port for SQL Server remote connections is 1433, you usually need to provide this along with the connection string. If you have chosen to install Express Edition as a default instance you can omit the `SQLEXPRESS` part aswell, so your `Server name` would look like

```
WIN-NVAAFR9N703,1433
```

Or if you have installed as a named instance

```
WIN-NVAAFR9N703\SQLEXPRESS,1433
```

Comment: (provider : TCP Provider, error 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.). Hmm, it all points to some firewall or network related issue. I just cant understand why, or where. I tried all the connection strings you provided + one extra all resulting with the same error.
WIN-NVAAFR9N703,1433
 WIN-NVAAFR9N703\SQLEXPRESS,1433
 WIN-NVAAFR9N703.\SQLEXPRESS,1433 Am I using the corredt "datasource" type to connect to a SQL Express database? In VS.